# std::mt19937 fails when std::uint_fast32_t is 4 bytes in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, random, c++17, mt19937

The problem I have encountered occurs when I'm trying to test the [cppreference example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) on generating pseudo-random numbers. Given the example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

on my machine, it results in a crash. By "crash" I mean that the process simply hangs and returns `0xC0000005` after few seconds.

I was wondering what might be causing it. GCC bug? My machine's malfunction? I decided to test and the results were quite surprising. For example, given the following, slightly modified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd{};
    std::mt19937_64 gen{rd()}; // notice the _64 here
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The code works as expected. I tried to understand why, so I quickly ran to [`std::mt19937` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine), where we can see its declaration:

```
template<
    class UIntType, 
    size_t w, size_t n, size_t m, size_t r,
    UIntType a, size_t u, UIntType d, size_t s,
    UIntType b, size_t t,
    UIntType c, size_t l, UIntType f
> class mersenne_twister_engine;
```

followed by two aliases:

```
using mt19937 = std::mersenne_twister_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 32, 624, 397, 31, 
                         0x9908b0df, 11, 
                         0xffffffff, 7, 
                         0x9d2c5680, 15, 
                         0xefc60000, 18, 1812433253>
```

and

```
using mt19937_64 = std::mersenne_twister_engine<std::uint_fast64_t, 64, 312, 156, 31,
                         0xb5026f5aa96619e9, 29,
                         0x5555555555555555, 17,
                         0x71d67fffeda60000, 37,
                         0xfff7eee000000000, 43, 6364136223846793005>
```

The interesting part is the very first `template` parameter for both aliases, the `std::uint_fast32_t` and `std::uint_fast64_t`. It's interesting because, diving into [GCC `<random>` implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.tcc?fbclid=IwAR0qtcHGGbglSqJUN8n2KZlDUblwp4IXypHdGFuvw9qJ2PPdRH4-7Rfpc0E#L369), we can see that, in the line `369`, the following is written:

```
__factor *= __detail::_Shift<_UIntType, 32>::__value;
```

Given the [`_Shift` implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h?fbclid=IwAR1QRkafdstf6lzBdLBrgCe1hqa1J4ixpW6RCcBcPbn9AmGoYrPlSleGDH0#L69) at line `72`:

```
template<typename _UIntType, size_t __w>
struct _Shift<_UIntType, __w, true> {
    static const _UIntType __value = _UIntType(1) << __w;
};
```

We can clearly see that an object of a type `_UIntType`, constructed with an argument `1` is being shifted by `__w` to the left. Why does that matter? Let's go back a little bit to the `std::mt19937` implementation. We can see that ultimately, we will be doing:

```
std::uint_fast32_t(1) << 32;
```

which might be okay, unless...

Unless the `sizeof (std::uint_fast32_t)` returns `4`, as it does on my machine. We are then dealing with 32 bit (assuming byte = 8 bits) unsigned integer value that is going to be shifted by 32 to the left. This is [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471843/7151494) and I believe this causes my program to crash.

So the question is: Is it simply a bug in some GCC implementations where `sizeof (std::uint_fast32_t) == 4`? Or something too clever for me is happening there and it's just my machine's malfunction?

I am using Windows 10, 64 bit, GCC <strike>8.2</strike> 8.1.

I have asked some colleagues to run some tests and every one of them succeded (no crashes). The thing is that on their machines the expression `sizeof (std::uint_fast32_t)` evaluated to `8`. Obviously, the UB is then gone.

**EDIT**: What's even more surprising is that when I seed the `gen` using some constant, the code behaves correctly, for example both:

```
std::mt19937 gen{10000000};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
}
```

,

```
std::mt19937 gen{5};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

and

```
std::mt19937 gen{0};
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

fail to reproduce the SEGFAULT. I managed to alter the example a little bit. Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd{};
    auto used = rd();
    std::cout << used << '\n';
}
```

This code consecutively produces the output `3499211612`. The thing is... This does NOT work (results in SEGFAULT):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::random_device rd{};
    auto used = rd();
    std::cout << used << '\n';
    std::mt19937 gen{3499211612};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

While this one does:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    /*std::random_device rd{};
    auto used = rd();
    std::cout << used << '\n';*/
    std::mt19937 gen{3499211612};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis{1, 6};

    for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Any idea how simply calling the `std::random_device`'s `operator()` alters the bahaviour of the engine? I feel like I should ask another question, but I am literally unable to even put into words what is happening in the examples...

**EDIT 2**:

`g++ -v` result:

> COLLECT_GCC=g++
>
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/users/felipe/desktop/mingw/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
>
> Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
>
> Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --with-tune=haswell --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp
>
> Thread model: posix
>
> gcc version 8.1.0 (GCC)

Comment: You say "a crash". Can you give details regarding this crash?

Comment: The process returns `0xC0000005`. Will include that in the question.

Comment: `sizeof (std::uint_fast32_t) evaluated to 8` is puzzling. Wouldn't 32 refer to 4 bytes?

Comment: No, since there is no requirement for that. That's the difference between `uint32_t` and `uint_fast32_t`. The later is not required to be 32 bits. It has to be at least 32 bits.

Comment: @SergeyA `uint_fast32_t` is at least 32 bits but can be more (the compiler picks a type which should be the fastest). GCC picks a 64-bit type on x86-64 Linux, though I don't know why that would be faster than a 32 bit type.

Comment: @interjay TIL. Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I mean what does your debugger say about it? Is there a signal? What's the backtrace?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the debugger emits SEGFAULT when executing `dis`' `operator()`. It stops on the `return this->_M_getval_pretr1()`, which apparently is not accessible for me. Maybe the debugger I am using is just limited or maybe I am doing something wrong. I also played a little with the code, please see the upcoming edit.

Comment: @Fureeish Please put details like these on your question. We still need a stack trace.

Comment: @M.M I did include it. It's the very first snippet of code and I stated that clearly. @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I am unfortunately unsure how could I obtain a stack trace regarding hidden implementation. At most I could scratch up this: `Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x0000000000493797 in std::random_device::_M_getval_pretr1() ()`. Regardless, **interjay**'s edited answer explained that there indeed is a bug with GCC's implementation of `std::random_device` and that is a satisfying answer.

Comment: @M.M edited, as requested

Comment: Thanks; also it would be helpful to show more detailed g++ version info (specifically, from `g++ -v`, the last 2 lines and the `Target:` line)

Comment: @M.M I have included the output of `g++ -v`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you've shown is not the cause for the crash. The full definition of `_Shift` is:

```
template<typename _UIntType, size_t __w,
     bool = __w < static_cast<size_t>
          (std::numeric_limits<_UIntType>::digits)>
  struct _Shift
  { static const _UIntType __value = 0; };

template<typename _UIntType, size_t __w>
  struct _Shift<_UIntType, __w, true>
  { static const _UIntType __value = _UIntType(1) << __w; };
```

This uses template specialization to check the size of `_UIntType` at compile-time. The first version is used when `__w` is greater than or equal than `std::numeric_limits<_UIntType>::digits`, which is the case here. So the resulting value is 0, and the left-shift isn't performed.

As for the crash itself: Apparently, [`std::random_device` doesn't work on Windows GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769671/stdrandom-device-not-working-in-g) and gives deterministic results (as you saw yourself). This may also be related to the cause of the crash. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042937/run-time-error-in-program-compiled-with-mingw-gcc-g-nuwen-distro) encountered a similar crash, also with GCC 8.2 on Windows.

As a workaround, you can use the [`Boost.Random`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_random.html) library instead which implements the same API.

Comment: +1'ed, but it didn't resolve my issue. I've made an edit, but I feel like I should've just asked a new question since it completely changes my view of the problem. May I ask about your opinion? Shall I delete the edit and ask a new question?

Comment: Although I think I also should accept this answer, since it answers the original question - it's not a bug regarding `std::uing_fast32_t`, it's *something* else, and that seems like a good enough summary to open a new question. I'll wait for the response though.

Comment: @Fureeish I think this is a good question and should not be deleted. As for opening another question regarding the cause for the crash, it seems that it has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042937/run-time-error-in-program-compiled-with-mingw-gcc-g-nuwen-distro - also using GCC 8.2 on Windows. Apparently `random_device` is buggy on Windows GCC (as you saw, even when it doesn't crash, it doesn't actually give random numbers). I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you! Also, the suggestion is much appreciated.